# Access to the path (..) is denied WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application I get the serial number of the hard disk and write it in text file (create the file if does not exist) .. here's my code:

```
string path = @"d:\RegisterKey.txt";
File.Create(path);
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
tw.WriteLine(GetHDSerialNo);
tw.Close();
```

The file created successfully, But the problem happening in TextWriter step :

> Access to the path 'd:\RegisterKey.txt' is denied.

Trying to run Visual studio as administrator but does not solve the problem.

Any suggestion

Thanks in advance

Abdusalam

Comment: The error message is Access to the path is denied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two streams open. [`File.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) creates and returns a new stream, and by default it doesn't allowed shared writing. You then attempt to write to it with another stream, which is blocked because `File.Create`'s stream is still open. Instead, you can hand that stream to the `StreamWriter`. Adjust your code like so:

```
string path = @"d:\RegisterKey.txt";
using (var stream = File.Create(path))
{
    using(TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        tw.WriteLine(GetHDSerialNo);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's work when I open VS as administrator. Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

The `File.Create` method creates the file and opens a FileStream so your file is already open.

take your stream like so :

```
var stream = File.Create(path);
```